# What would prevent DTMF tones being recognised (modem to modem)?

Tags: telephone, modem

A bit of back story: the SEGA Dreamcast had a dial up modem which was used for online play, in the absence of dialup ISPs it's now common practice to directly connect the DC to a USB dial up modem and route the connection through a PC via ppp.

Some revisions of the Dreamcast require a voltage on the line to dial out, and in this case a solution was found by inducing a voltage by wiring a 9v battery and resistor into the phone line. (http://dreamcast.onlineconsoles.com/phpBB2/guides_pcdcwin98.php#10)

However even still it appears some USB modems don't recognise the signals from the Dreamcast. For example if I connect a standard phone to the line in place of the Dreamcast, the tones are recognised by the PC, but the dialling of the DC isn't recognised at all!

What could cause this to happen? Why would one device generate DTMF codes that work, and another device not? If I connect a phone directly to the DC I can hear the tones being dialled but there must be some difference between those generated by the DC and those by the phone.

Also, it seems that even if I blindly answer the Dreamcast (by sending the ATA command to the receiving USB modem) the Dreamcast doesn't recognise the call was answered, perhaps that's related and this is more than just the DTMF tones...

I'd appreciate any suggestions that might help to get these two modems communicating!

Answer (score 4):

DTMF tones are only required for dialing out through an exchange. When connecting directly from modem to modem you are already connected, so the phone number is redundant!

However the Dreamcast modem may expect to get various tones and voltages during the call (eg. dial tone, line voltage) while the receiving modem won't normally answer unless it gets ringing voltage (~90V at 20Hz). You can force the receiving modem to answer with `ATA`, then it should send carrier (which the Dreamcast modem will be listening for after it has finished dialing) and the two modems should talk to each other.

To trick the Dreamcast modem into thinking it is connected to a phone line you can connect it to an *actual* phone line, then quickly unplug it and plug into the other modem after it has dialed. A switch would make this easier, or you could build a 'telephone line simulator' which emulates all the essential functions of an exchange (dial tone, ringing voltage, line voltages with current regulation, linking the audio signal from one line to the other etc.). The one thing you *won't* need is DTMF tone recognition.

If you have followed the usual procedure for connecting a Dreamcast to a PC modem but it doesn't work then most likely the PC modem is not compatible with your crude line voltage circuit, or it has a software issue. If you have access to two phone lines then first get it to work from one line to the other through the exchange, then try the single phone line trick.